# I need an executable that does nothing

Tags: exe

How can I create an executable that keeps running and shows up in task manager, but does nothing? I need it for a program, I can use every language, or if it already exists it's better.

Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm not a noob, I can find these informations on my own, just looking for an idea, no need to downvote...

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just issued a close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a C code to do the job, you can use the thread sleep method to decrease the CPU load

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
  char a;

  while((a=getchar())!='z')// to quit the program when z is pressed
  { 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good example in C#

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        while(true) {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // So we don't spam the CPU too much
        }
    }
}
```

Another example for an program you actually could quit without too much hassle.
It just waits for you to press Enter. :)

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me...

Comment: Both, my compiler throws me errors (need = or , or ; before "using")

Comment: Both my examples should be working fine on their own. If you create a fresh C# console program and just take what's in my Main-methods, either one should work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with .cmd extension and write this into that file:

```
:BEGIN
GOTO BEGIN
```

You can double click on it, and call it from any programming language you want with this like code:

```
system("/path_to_your_code/your_file.cmd");
```